# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST i looked everywhere but i haven’t found a solutin

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-8

so this is my first time posting a question and i hope i get some help.
this is my code for web.php file:

```
Route::get('/blogs', 'BlogsController@index')->name('blogs');
Route::get('/blogs/create', 'BlogsController@create')->name('create');
Route::post('/blogs/store', 'BlogsController@store')->name('blogs.store');
```

and this one is the form field in html:

```
<form action="{{ route('blogs.store') }}" method="post">
    @csrf
</form>
```

Comment: are you using blogs.store directly in form action attribute?

Comment: yes i tried using the name i specified for the route and also tried to use the uri. nothing seems to work.

Comment: if you're using a blade template, then can you follow the answer I posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form element should be as follow:

```
<form action="{{ route('blogs.store') }}" method="post">
```

Comment: i dont know if it worked or not because now im having such an ugly error.

Comment: ntegrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `blogs` (`title`, `body`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)

Comment: ``` $blog = new Blog();
        $blog->title = $request->title;
        $blog->body =$request->body;
        $blog->save();
        return redirect('/blogs');```

Comment: It worked, this new error is something else

Comment: Your blog title was empty that's why you got that error. In your database, you have set 
 title column to Not Null.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML form, when you call the route post, it is incorrect. Use the following code:

routes/web.php

```
Route::prefix('blogs')->group(function () {
    Route::get('', 'BlogsController@index')->name('blogs');
    Route::get('create', 'BlogsController@create')->name('create');
    Route::post('store', 'BlogsController@store')->name('blogs.store');
});
```

And your form should be like this:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('blogs.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    {{-- Form Data - Start --}}

    {{-- Form Data - End --}}
</form>
```